# 'Incomplete \iffalse' error when migrating to biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm new to LaTeX, and using it to write a Masters thesis, in Overleaf. We were provided some LaTeX resources which used natbib but I've found I would rather use biblatex for the ibid functionality. I've changed:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\bibliography{Zotero}
```

to:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Zotero}
...
\printbibliography
```

But I get the error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty:235:
Incomplete \iffa
lse; all text was ignored after line 27.
<inserted text> 
            \fi 
l.235 \input{logreq.def}
```

The strange thing is line 27 is far before where the usepackage command is - it contains some commented text.

There were some .bst files I imported that came from the resources provided by the uni. If I understand correctly, those will be invalidated, but I'm no longer referencing them - but do I need to replace them with something else?

**EDIT: In trying to minimally reproduce the error in a new project, I traced the problem to a conflict with \usepackage{program}! According to the file I got this from, this is useful for quoting code...**

**I suppose my new question is: Assuming I want to keep the package {program}, is there some way to resolve this? Why this conflict? (And any tips as to why I might want to use program, or alternatives, would be welcome as a side note - though I will read up on this myself.)**

Comment: You are not giving enough information. Delete the auxiliary files (bbl, aux etc) and recompile. If the error persist you will have to make a small complete example and show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Overleaf doesn't show auxiliary files, but does give the option to 'recompile from scratch', which might be equivalent? I'm afraid I don't have an editor or compiler set up myself - I'd far prefer to stick to Overleaf to handle these things.

I was hoping I'd made an elementary mistake, either leaving something out in my .tex file, having improper/no .bst, or not setting the compiler to biber.

If you really think I should provide a minimal test case which provokes this error, I can try to do that tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome! Recompile from scratch is equivalent. Failing that, we need an example which we can use to reproduce the error. It is certainly not obvious that error has anything to do with the change to Biblatex from the information provided.

Comment: Note that I would not recommend relying on OverLeaf for an important project such as a thesis. You are at the mercy of OverLeaf and the service providers OverLeaf relies on. Unless you have a paid account, you cannot keep your work private in any effective way. Moreover, OverLeaf is mind-numbingly slow and, so, frustrating to use even for quite short documents. It is also difficult to diagnose problems, at least on Windows, because the log file is displayed horribly in NotePad.

Comment: In trying to minimally reproduce the error I have now traced the error to a conflict with \usepackage{program} - thanks for encouraging me to do so and sorry not to have done that before posting the question. (I will edit the question now.)

@cfr Thanks, I'll take that on board. Though to counter: I thought that a cloud-based project would protect against certain eventualities, and I surely in the space of a month or two Overleaf isn't going to suddenly going stop hosting me?

Comment: There have been other cases in which cloud-based companies have disappeared, essentially, with their users' files. You certainly should make sure that everything is also stored elsewhere. Unless you have extensive, inside knowledge of the company's financial health, management, legal position etc. etc., of course you can't count on it completely. Put it this way: it is unlikely OverLeaf will last forever. (Such is life.) Probably, it will not disappear suddenly. But, of course, it might. (I don't suppose they have the conscience to follow SilentCircle, but who knows?)

Comment: Having stuff in the cloud is good. Having stuff only in the cloud - especially on only one bit of the cloud - is obviously not.

Comment: In any case, we need an example in order to be of any help at all.

Comment: If you have identified the problematic package, please put together a small document that reproduces the exact error you got. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). That document would load as few packages as possible - it would of course load the packages you have identified as conflicting. It would also contain as few lines of text as possible, just enough to replicate the problem.

Comment: I just compile a very short document with only `biblatex` and `program` and it worked flawlessly. So there must be more to the problem you have. We will definitely have to see a MWE to investigate further.

Comment: @moewe I can reproduce the problem if I load `program` before `biblatex`. `program` makes the | active and this leads to an error when `loqref` is loaded. Looking at the code of `program` I can only warn to use it. This package (re)defines tons of commands without any checking if there are already defined. It is bound to lead to problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, thank you, I didn't think of loading `program` first. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem if I load `program` before `biblatex`. `program` makes the | active and this leads to an error when `loqref` is loaded. Loading `program` later avoids the error but looking at the code of `program` I can only warn to use it. This package (re)defines tons of commands without any checking if they are already defined. It is bound to lead to problems.

One small example of changed commands is

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}
\d{A} \t{e}{e} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `We also redefine \( and \) as \begin{programbox} and \end{programbox}` is found in the package header. *This* would have a very big impact on documents!

Comment: @egreg I didn't saw this gem ;-). But the whole code made me shudder.